# Regex: matching up to the first occurrence of a character

Tags: regex

I am looking for a pattern that matches everything **until** the first occurrence of a specific character, say a ";" - a **semicolon**.

I wrote this:

```
/^(.*);/
```

But it actually matches everything (including the semicolon) until the last occurrence of a semicolon.

Comment: `/^(.*?);/` should also work (it's called **non-greedy**), but the given answers using `[^;]*` are better.

Comment: how would you select everything, after semicolon, and not semicolon itself.

Comment: see this works `\w+(?!([^]+;)|;)` but this doesn't why? `.+(?!([^]+;)|;)`

Comment: Pascal, you should have written that as an answer!

Answer (score 776, accepted):

You need

```
/^[^;]*/
```

The `[^;]` is a *character class*, it matches everything but a semicolon.

^ (start of line anchor) is added to the beginning of the regex so only the first match on each line is captured. This may or may not be required, depending on whether possible subsequent matches are desired.

To cite the [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) manpage:

> You can specify a character class, by enclosing a list of characters in [] , which will match any character from the list. If the first character after the "[" is "^", the class matches any character not in the list.

This should work in most regex dialects.

*Note:* The pattern will match everything up to the first semicolon, but excluding the semicolon. Also, it will match the whole line if there is no semicolon. If you want the semicolon included in the match, add a semicolon at the end of the pattern.

Comment: The great part about this solution is that also matches end of the line, e.g. in my case I had `foo=bar;baz=bax;bab=baf` and it matched `bab=baf` even there is no `;` Exactly what I need. Not sure why it works though if spec says matches everything but the target symbol...

Comment: I learned the hard way that `/^[^;]*/` will also match strings with no semi-colon.  If you don't want it to match sentences with semi-colon, use `/^(.*?);/`

Comment: Just realized that I made the same point as @skryvets.  Going to let my comment stand though, because it's slightly different phrasing might help people.

Comment: @oymonk: Yes, good point. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but it checks only the first occurence. Here is the [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/69b9d603e46c). I want to match until the last occurence.

Comment: @AmineKOUIS: Yes, it finds only the first occurrence, because of the anchor ("^"). This is explained under "Note" in my answer.

Answer (score 457):

Would;

```
/^(.*?);/
```

work?

The `?` is a lazy operator, so the regex grabs as little as possible before matching the `;`.

Comment: ya, but following the bicarbonate extension to Tim Toady, I believe negated character classes win as lazy quantifier includes backtraking. +1 anyway.

Comment: Worth reading on the performance topic: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance

Comment: Why the matching include `;` [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/1dad381d1d84)

Comment: @AmineKOUIS It does, but the group does not contain the `;`. In JS you can use array indexing to pull the group out of the `exec` result. Alternatively, if you do not want the semi colon in the match result and you're happy to match strings that contain no `;` then you can use sleske's answer `/^[^;]*/`

Answer (score 53):

`/^[^;]*/`

The [^;] says match anything except a semicolon.  The square brackets are a set matching operator, it's essentially, match any character in this set of characters, the `^` at the start makes it an inverse match, so match anything *not* in this set.

Comment: Be aware that the first ^ in this answer gives the regex a completely different meaning: It makes the regular expression look only for matches starting from the beginning of the string. In this case, that would effectively be a no-op *if* you run the regular expression only once. If you want to look for multiple matches within a single string, the first ^ would have to go.

Comment: He did say that he wanted to match everything until the first occurrence of a semicolon, so I assumed that he meant from the start of the string.

Comment: The anchor has no effect since only a single match is wanted.

Answer (score 24):

**None** of the proposed answers did work for me. (e.g. in notepad++)
But

```
^.*?(?=\;)
```

did.

Answer (score 22):

Try `/[^;]*/`

Google `regex character classes` for details.

Answer (score 14):

sample text:

```
"this is a test sentence; to prove this regex; that is g;iven below"
```

If for example we have the sample text above, the regex `/(.*?\;)/` will give you everything until the first occurence of semicolon (`;`), including the semicolon: `"this is a test sentence;"`

Comment: it is not necessary to escape `;` char becaut it is not regex special character. Grouping `()` is not required as well. You can go with `/.*?;/`

Comment: yes, you are quite right. the escaping was more like "better safe than sorry"

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. So the ? makes the match end on the first occurence? What's the name of this... (let's call it) property of the regex?

Comment: @Parziphal the `?` character makes the match **lazy** (matching as few times as possible). Think of the regex matching characters up until the first semicolon then it doesn't go any farther because it gives up (lazy ;) )

Answer (score 12):

Try `/[^;]*/`

That's a negating [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 7):

This was very helpful for me as I was trying to figure out how to match all the characters in an xml tag including attributes. I was running into the "matches everything to the end" problem with:

```
/<simpleChoice.*>/
```

but was able to resolve the issue with:

```
/<simpleChoice[^>]*>/
```

after reading this post. Thanks all.

Comment: I had found that it is way more efficient to actually parse(each language or framework has its own classes for that) html/xml because of it's machine format, regex's are for natural language.

Comment: Nice. I used this to fix xml documents with syntax errors in `<!DOCTYPE>` tag. Since parser wasn't able to handle it.

Answer (score 5):

this is not a regex solution, but something simple enough for your problem description. Just split your string and get the first item from your array.

```
$str = "match everything until first ; blah ; blah end ";
$s = explode(";",$str,2);
print $s[0];
```

output

```
$ php test.php
match everything until first
```

Answer (score 5):

This will match up to the first occurrence only in each string and will ignore subsequent occurrences.

```
/^([^;]*);*/
```

Answer (score 3):

`"/^([^\/]*)\/$/"` worked for me, to get only top "folders" from an array like:

```
a/   <- this
a/b/
c/   <- this
c/d/
/d/e/
f/   <- this
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above match a string if it does *not* contain the character.

If you want to have match only if the character exists (and no match otherwise), you should use this regex:

```
/^(.*?);/
```

Answer (score 2):

Really kinda sad that no one has given you the correct answer....

In regex,  ?  makes it non greedy. By default regex will match as much as it can (greedy)

Simply add a ?  and it will be non-greedy and match as little as possible!

Good luck, hope that helps.

Comment: This heavily depends on the actual regex **implementation** and not every implementation has non-greedy mode.

Answer (score 2):

This works for getting the content from the beginning of a line till the first word,

```
/^.*?([^\s]+)/gm
```

Comment: It doesn't work, check it [here](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/e76378cbaaa5). It matches only the first word.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem including all the characters until the first comma after the word `entity_id`. The solution that worked was this in Bigquery:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(line_items,r'entity_id*[^,]*')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem of finding and selecting the text till first occurrence of character in my IDE:

Just use this:

```
^(.*?)
```

And append it with the character that you want the text to be selected, i.e., in my case i wanted to change train_0001 to train_1001:

```
^(.*?)_0
```

Just did the above and changed the sentence directly in IDE. Hope it helps. Thanks!