# PHP regular expression match first occurrences?

Tags: php, regex

```
http://someurlhere.com|http://sometexturl.com|sometexthere
```

i want to extract only the first url which is before the | , http://someurlhere.com

i have written regular expression

```
\bhttp(.*)\|\b
```

but its capture all the occurences of |

Thanx help is appreciated

Comment: Not really an answer to your question; but consider using `explode()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You're trying to get the first part of text that is an URL (eg. prefixed with http://)? Does the http:// have to be part of the resulting match? Because as of now, your match would be `://someurlhere.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex. I see you tagged it PHP.

```
$boom = explode('|', 'http://someurlhere.com|sometexturl.com|sometexthere');
$url = $boom[0];
echo $url;
```

Output:

```
http://someurlhere.com
```

http://codepad.org/xnW0FTfA

Answer (score 9):

Make  the `.*` ungreedy : `.*?`

```
\bhttp(.*?)\|\b
```

If you want to match only after the first `|` do:

```
\|http://(.*?)\|
```

with this, the url is in `$1`

Comment: sorry i tried this one ,its works but for this kind http://someurlhere.com|http://sometexturl.com|sometexthere
not working

Comment: @Fawad: What do you obtain with your example?

Comment: Thanx got it , i was using global regular expression , thanx again . can u do me one more help . how can i extract only url becuase of this pattern | is also coming in match :)

Comment: i have edited the main question can u please read again thanx

Comment: @Fawad: with my second regex, the url is in the first capture group `$1`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a exact answer, but I will point you towards information that help you solve this issue!

[Regex: matching up to the first occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013124/regex-matching-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character)