# Matching up to the first occurrence of a character

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have been reading this post but It have not solved my problem:
[Regex: matching up to the first occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013124/regex-matching-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character)

I have this variable:

```
$attributes = ID=CUFF.1;Name=CG12402-RB;Note=Parial_gene
```

I have written this script:

```
if ($attributes  =~ /Name=([^;]*)/)  { 
            $genename =  $-[0];
         $name = substr($attributes, $genename);
```

If I print `$name` this is the output: `Name=CG12402;Note=Parial_gene`

But I want my output like this: `Name=CG12402`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
/(Name=[^;]+)-/
```

Your original regex `/Name=([^;]*)/` will capture any character after a literal `Name=` up to `;`

However, for the example you provide your regex shouldn't produce the result you said it does. It should capture: `CG12402-RB`