# Extracting substring ending with some sign but without this sign

Tags: regex, r, string

I have some string

```
string <- "Shakira - Wolf - 02.Hips don't lie.mp3"
```

I want only the first part, so the name of the artist. I use regex like this

```
stri_extract_all_regex(string, "^.*?-")
```

The output: `"Shakira -"`. But I don't want `" -"`. How to write regex which allows me to take only the substring which stands *before* the first `" -"`?

Comment: Starred answer works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013124/regex-matching-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character

Comment: Nothing works the way I want, maybe because I have several "-" in my string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negated character-class method succeeds:

```
> stri_extract_all_regex(string, "^[^-]+")
[[1]]
[1] "Shakira "
```

Challenged by The Other David I'm attempting now to select only the spaces between alpha characters but to also use that function and therefore do it with a "positive" selection strategy:

```
string <- "Shakira and Friends - Wolf - 02.Hips don't lie.mp3"
stri_extract_all_regex(string, "^[[:alpha:]]+( *[[:alpha:]])*")
[[1]]
[1] "Shakira and Friends"
```

Comment: This still has a space in it. It should be `stri_extract_all_regex(string, "^[^ -]+")[[1]]`

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need (without using external packages)

```
sub(" -.*", "", string)
## [1] "Shakira"
```

**Explanation**

This simply matches `" -"` and everything after it until the end of the string and replaces it with nothing. Which basically leaves you with everything before the first `" -"`

---

If you insist on `stringi` package (for speed) you could use `stri_extract_first` with the simple regex of

```
stri_extract_first(string, regex = "[A-Za-z]+")
## [1] "Shakira"
```

Comment: `sub`, the small and humble solution that I'm sure Shakira prefers.

Comment: @thelatemail, `gsub` will also work with this specific regex, but `sub` seems safer

Comment: I'll +1 yours (deleted mine) I prefer `sub` in this case.

Comment: @hwnd, you should probably leave it in order to make this Q/A richer

Comment: @DavidArenburg no that is ok. Btw you can remove the `$` anchor it is not necessary really =)

Answer (score 2):

How about using `strsplit`?

```
strsplit(string, split = " -")[[1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
string <- "Shakira - Wolf - 02.Hips don't lie.mp3"

library(rex)
re_matches(string,
  rex(capture(zero_or_more(any, type='lazy')), spaces, "-"))$'1'

#> [1] "Shakira"
```