# Extract a word with REGEX

Tags: regex

I have some expression Like `XXXX_I(YYYY)` with `XXXX` fix I integer (1,2,3, etc) and `YYYY` string could be anything, any length. Is it possible d'extract just `XXXX_I`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: `[^(]*` or `.*?(?=\()` or `\W(.*?)\(`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: matching up to the first occurrence of a character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013124/regex-matching-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character)

Comment: Does the string always start with XXXX?

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options considering this is a very vague topic. A few options

```
[^(]*
```

**Gets text except (until) (**

---

```
.*?(?=\()
```

**Gets text up to (**

---

```
\W(.*?)\(
```

**Gets word before (**

---

```
\d{4}_I
```

**Gets four digits I then any single character**

---

```
\d{4}_I(?=\()
```

**Gets four digits I any character then (**

---

## Which one would I use?

```
(?<=\W|^)\d{4}_I*?(?=\()
```

Is a very versatile solution which is still strict on enforcing the rules.

Or if you are using a more limited Regex flavor such as JavaScript:

```
(?:\W|^)\d{4}_I*?(?=\()
```

In which case you might have an extra space at the beginning but it would still work well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pattern

```
[^(]+
```

or to be more strict on 4 digits and `_I` you can use

```
\d{4}_I
```