# Nearest match using RegEx

Tags: regex, linux, string

I have a string - `howareyoumyworld`
Using RegEx, I only want to match the string till the nearest `w` i.e. I want to match `how` and not `howareyoumyw`.

Please help!

Comment: Try `^[^w]*w` or `^.*?w`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: matching up to the first occurrence of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013124/regex-matching-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lazy quantifier `?`

```
^\w+?w
```