# Spring Cloud Gateway - Rewrite path syntax

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

The following example is given in the documenation:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: rewritepath_route
        uri: http://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/foo/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/foo/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

I have a lot of services, so instead of hard-coding `foo` in the `RewritePath` filter, I'd simply like to drop that part dynamically.

I came up with this but it's not working

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - RewritePath=/(?<base>.*)/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
      routes:
      - id: rewritepath_route
        uri: http://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/foo/**
```

How does the correct reg exp syntax look like?

Comment: It's a Java regex. Looks fine to me.

Comment: `RewritePath=/(?<base>.*?)/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}` I added a lazy operator ? to match only the first segment.

Answer (score 3):

I added a `?` operator after `<base>.*` to match only the first part of the path.
Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013124/regex-matching-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - RewritePath=/(?<base>.*?)/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
      routes:
      - id: rewritepath_route
        uri: http://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/foo/**
```

Also I didn't realize that it's just plain java regex, thanks @spencergibb.

<sup>(Looking at the source code it's not magic at all, if someone is stuck with a similar problem I encourage to do the same. It's easily readable code which does what it promises to do.)</sup>